# How to troubleshoot a lockup/freeze

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, custom-roms, logging, troubleshooting, system-freeze

I have a GNex running on CN(A) 3.8. It has started to lockup/freeze when the screen is off. So far it occurs mostly overnight while it's charging. I have to pull the battery to resolve. I believe it started a couple of ROM updates ago. I have not gone through the step of doing a factory wipe (but have cleared the cache/Dalvik), etc, but I was wondering what tools does Android have to troubleshoot freezes, etc.

Is there a system log, etc that I can look at to see if there's a pattern of what is occurring at the time of freeze?

Answer (score 2):

There are apps that let you look at the system log, like [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en).

What I would do is start logging before you charge it at night and then take a look at the result in the morning. The log will probably be staggering but the errors should show up in red.

Comment: Thanks. I've switched ROMs (CM10) and that seems to have resolved the issue, but I've downloaded the recommended app in case I want to dig into any future issues.

Comment: Just remember to do a full wipe between flashing ROMs. This includes Dalvik Cache which is under advanced options in the Clockwork Mod recovery screen. If you do a full wipe between ROMs and you still have errors make sure the ROM is for your exact phone model and service provider. Have fun! PS I'm also running CM10 on my GS3 and no problems yet!